# Fortran derived datatype used before defined

Tags: types, module, fortran, derived

How to include the derived datatype (the type, not variable) between modules with `use module, ONLY:` statement?

More description: In my `module1` I defined a derived datatype (let's call it my_datatype) and some data (let's call it my_data) of this datatype. In my `module2` I need to use `my_data`. Since my module1 contains many procedures that `module2` does not need, I want to use the `ONLY` statement to only include `my_data`. However, without including the datatype it will give me the error:

```
Derive datatype 'my_type' is used before defined at "type(my_type),intent(out)::A"
```

It is obvious that `module2` does not recognize `my_datatype` defined in `module1` because I did not pass it. But what is the syntax to include a derived type in 'use module, only' statement? I am using Fortran 2003.

```
  module step1
  implicit none
     type my_type
        integer::id
        integer,dimension(2)::my_data
     end type my_type

     type(my_type)::A
  end module step1

  module step2
  use step1,only:A
  implicit none
  contains
     subroutine change_A(A)            
        type(my_type),intent(inout)::A
        A%id = 1
        A%my_data(1) = 1
        A%my_data(2) = 2                    
     end subroutine change_A
  end module step2

  program test
  ! program is in a different folder
  use step1
  use step2
     implicit none
     call change_A(A)
  end program test
```

Comment: Welcome. Please post *real code* in your questions. Especially do so when showing any error messages.  Also, show *complete* error messages. See [ask] and [mcve]. The code you show compiles just fine if I remove the nonsense and add `my_data%i = 1` into `do_something_to_my_data`. You do not need the datatype in scope to work with the variable.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I have revised the question as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, it is giving me error "derived datatype is used before it is defined". It looks like module2 does not recognize my_datatype defined in module1.

Well, yeah. Of course module2 does not recognize your datatype, because it's defined in module1 and in your 'use'-statement you say you only want to use the variable my_data. Simply include the datatype in the 'use'-statement, and it will be known in module2

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Could you show me the syntax of using datatype in the "use" statement? I could not find it.

Comment: It is exactly the same as with variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Given your updated question, here is how to implement the fix suggested by others:

(EDIT: implementing suggestions from the comments:

1. Only import the type from module step1 in module step2.
2. Only import A from step1 and change_A from step2 in the main program.
3. Do take note that the dummy argument "A" in the routine "change_A" bears no relation to the "A" from module step1 in the definition in the routine. I change the name of the dummy to illustrate this point.

)

```
module step1
  implicit none
  type my_type
     integer::id
     integer,dimension(2)::my_data
  end type my_type

  type(my_type)::A

end module step1

module step2
  use step1, only: my_type
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine change_A(dummy)
    type(my_type),intent(inout) :: dummy
    dummy%id = 1
    dummy%my_data(1) = 1
    dummy%my_data(2) = 2
  end subroutine change_A
end module step2

program test
  ! program is in a different folder
  use step1, only: A
  use step2, only: change_A
  implicit none

  call change_A(A)
  write(*,*) A

end program test
```

I have added `my_type` to the 'use' statement.

Comment: I think it's worth explicitly stating that `A` in the subroutine is not the module entity.

Comment: Yes, the A in the `only` clause does almost nothing.